# How do you enable L2TP in a Cisco Firewall?

Tags: cisco, l2tp

I am trying to find out how to allow L2TP traffic through a PIX 515e firewall.  Windows 2003 is already configured.  Thank you.

EDIT:  6.1(2) is the sh version response.

Comment: What firmware are you running? 6.3, 7.2, or 8.2(or anything in between)?

Comment: I don't know.  How can I tell?

Comment: run 'sh ver' ..

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/products/hw/vpndevc/ps2030/products_configuration_example09186a0080094a5a.shtml) document from Cisco should help you.